# What to store an IP as in Java

Tags: java, mysql, type-conversion

I am connecting a Java program to a MySQL database, so I need the IP to connect it. Hard coding the IP is obviously a bad idea so I made a config. My only problem is I am not sure what to store the IP as in the variable. I looked around an a lot of places say int, but I don't see how that can be correct because integers don't have decimals. What should I do?

Comment: An `int[]` could work

Answer (score 5):

Edit: The answer from Mattias F is more appropriate to your situation. That being said, I'll explain why you've heard that an IP address can be stored in an integer.

An IPv4 address consists of 4 octects, or 4 bytes of data. Incidentally, that's exactly how much information a 32-bit integer can hold. Here are the methods to go both ways:

```
public static int ipStringToInteger (final String ip)
{
    int value = 0;
    final String[] parts = ip.split ("\\.");
    for (final String part : parts)
        value = (value << 8) + Integer.parseInt (part);
    return value;
}
public static String ipIntegerToString (int ip)
{
    final String[] parts2 = new String[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        System.out.println ("Value : " + (ip & 0xff));
        parts2[3 - i] = Integer.toString (ip & 0xff);
        ip >>= 8;
    }
    return parts2[0] + '.' + parts2[1] + '.' + parts2[2] + '.' + parts2[3];
}
```

Edit: Integer.valueOf replace with Integer.parseInt, thanks to Unihedron

Comment: This is way to much work for just storing an IP address in your program. The framwork he is using is most probably using a String anyways, and if not, it would be an int[], and both of them is really easy do handle. Compressing the IP address into an int using byte operations just to save space is not neccesary at all in this example.

Comment: @MattiasF You gave your answer, and to that I had nothing additional to contribute. You'll notice that, in the question, he wondered how an IP address could be stored in an integer. I believe I explained that. There is no one right answer

Comment: Also, I don't know who, but someone misunderstands the concept of a down-vote

Comment: @Unihedron Thanks for the edit. It improves performance by preventing auto-unboxing

Comment: My interpretation was that the question was about how to store an IP address in his program. He mentioned that he did research and that he found that it's possible to store it as an integer, but he understood that it would be impractical, of which I agree with him. Given his (assumed) lack of experience using java I would really not reccomend using your strategy as it's way to complicated for what he wants to do, so my down vote was based on his current knowledge and to make it easy to use, easely maintained, and easy for him to understand.

Comment: @Unihedron making a comment explaining how your change would be an improvement would allow etherous to choose if they want to incorporate it.

Comment: But in an application where you need to store millions of IP addresses in memory, I really like your answer. Byte operations can be messy and your solution is good for storing an IP into an integer. Don't get me wrong, I really like your solution, but for this particular question, its a little too complicated

Comment: @MattiasF My answer was not intended to compete with yours. Given the context, your answer should definitely be preferred. I grant you that my answer would have been more appropriate as a comment, but, please remember that downvotes are intended only for the most blatantly incorrect and irresponsible of answers

Comment: I agree with you completely. I don't think your solution were either  incorrect or irresponsible. I think our two answers are colliding in some since, since your answer is the answer to what he think he wants, and mine is an answer to what he actually wants. My down vote were just to make him realize that, but I will remove my down vote and let him (and others) decide for them self as i don't think your answer is wrong in any way.

Answer (score 2):

As this is in a config file I would just store it all as a string for readability, but you can store it as whatever you want. If this is your IP: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", I would just save it as it is in your config file. Then the rest is dependent on what format your framework for connecting to the database want it on. If it needs a string, you are done, if you need an int[] you just split on "." and do Integer.parseInt on the result from split. Its also possible to have each "xxx" separated with something completely different or even have them on separate lines, but that will both mean more work for you when you parse or lesser readability.

Answer (score 0):

store IP in properties file

**Message.properties**

```
#Mysql server Configuration 
username = root
password = india
ip = 192.168.1.1
```

MySQLConnection.java

```
Properties pro = new Properties();
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Message.properties");
pro.load(in);
String userName = pro.getProperty("username");
String password = pro.getProperty("password");
String IP = pro.getProperty("ip");
```